# ckeditor default style or class for the textarea

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

Does anyone know how i can make my textarea in a ckeditor object, use a class or custom style so i can show to the user something similar to what is getting rendered in the site?

Thanx

So i'm using bodyClass: 'class' in the config object, i use firebug and see the iframe body has my class applied, but it doesn't get the classes properties neither from my CSS, nor from contents.css (ckeditor)...

Well i was able to do it, adding an event to the object like this:

```
editor.on('instanceReady', function(){
        $('#'+divname).find('iframe:first').contents().find('body').css({
                'background-color':'#000000',
                'font-family':'arial',
                'font-size':'12pt',
                'color':'#cdcdcd'
        });
    });
```

if anyone has the real solution, i think bodyClass should be it, i will gladly change my code.

Thanx

Comment: I just stumbled on this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aY5qm8KCGU). It looks like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit the css file located at contents.css - edit the .cke_editable class to whatever suits your needs. Works 24/7